# How to share Google API authorizations for a Google Apps Script add-on with other Google Cloud project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-apps-script-addon

### Components of the system

- [Published Google Apps Script add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish) (*"add-on"*) and also [published on the G Suite marketplace for domain-wide installation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide#bundling_with_an_existing_google_apps_marketplace_app)

  - still in its original GCP project *P1*
  - has the OAuth2 client ID that was generated automatically when the script was created
- Web application (*"web-app"*) in Google Cloud, for quota reasons preferably in a separate project *P2* (but same owner and in same organization as the *add-on* project). It is replacing a web-app with the same functionality that was until now part of the *add-on*.

*client-secrets-addon.json* looks like this:

```
{"web":{
"client_id": "57...1t.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"project_id": "project-id-95...70",
"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":
"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_secret": "K2...y1",
"redirect_uris": ["https://script.google.com/oauthcallback"]
}}
```

Owner has no permission to add a different redirect URI to it. Apparently a security constraint specific to the default client of any Apps Script project. So it seems, we cannot just use the same client ID by the new *web-app*.

### Use-cases

#### Add-on installation by resource owner

A G Suite administrator or a resource owner installs the *add-on* for files in Google Drive. During the installation, the user is presented OAUTH2 consent screen to grant the necessary scopes to Google Drive and a few other Google API scopes (including offline-access).

#### Add-on is triggered

While user with-out a Google account works with a *resource owner*'s file in Google Drive (*file*), the *add-on* is triggered. The *add-on* is "executed as me" (the script owner). On behalf of the *resource owner*, the *add-on* sends notifications to other users.

#### Users respond to notifications

When receiving the notification, users (not Google account) are directed to the *web-app* for certain actions. As a result, the *web-app* again needs access to the *file*.

### Problems

1. The *web-app* was earlier implemented in the same script as the *add-on*. There are many *resource owners* and administrators who already have granted the scopes and we don't want to break the *add-on* because of missing scopes for the new *web-app*.
2. Since the *resource owner* is not present at the time when the *web-app* is accessing the *file*, the *web-app* needs the scopes during installation just like the *add-on* has.

### Requirements

1. The optimal user experience would be, if there was only one authorization to complete for the *resource owner* during the *add-on* installation.
2. Existing *resource owners* aren't required to repeat authorization in the new *web-app* in order to avoid disruptions.
3. In Google account's list of apps with access, showing *add-on* and *web-app* as one app, and revoking access would definitely revoke access for both components.
4. If the only option to meet these requirements, we would consider to host the *web-app* in the same project as the *add-on*.

What would be the best approach to share the already completed Google API authorizations of the *add-on*, so the new *web-app* can use them?